# Firebase signup with Facebook, create user with Cloud Function

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just started an iOS app using swift and Firebase. I implemented a Facebook login with Firebase, but I would like to create a user with all its Facebook data (firstname, lastname, etc...) once he signs up.

I have seen that everybody does that from the client (iOS) by updating the user values from data retrieved from Facebook. I would like to do the same, but server-side, so from a cloud function.

I would like a cloud function that once the user signed up using the facebook provider, fetches its facebook data and updates the document.

I have tried to find any piece of example with a trigger but did not find anything.

Comment: You can send `accessToken` to server side api ,The server fetches data and insert it in a firebase database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase's [`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential) with the `Facebook AccessToken` you get when you auth a user

```js
facebookAccessToken.then(data => {
    const facebookProvider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;
    const credential = provider.credential(data.accessToken.toString());
    firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
    .then(function(userCredential) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(userCredential));
    });
```